# Undefined variable _SERVER

Tags: php

Last day, i creating a website using `php`, i'm using `htaccess`to make the url more friendly, i had some features that manipulate the `header` image, documents, ets.

But suddenly, i didnt why, the website become an plain text, no `css` or `js`, and showing an error in the top of the page like this

> Undefined variable: _SERVER in B:\xampp\htdocs\creation\myportofolio\v1\source\me-init.php on line 10

I think that was nothing wrong with my code, i tried everything, google doesn't give me much, i tried to rewrite the whole code, and write like below.

```
<?php
  class init {
    public function __construct() {
        echo $_SERVER;
    }
  }
?>
```

I know, it should be a warning appear to tell me that `$_SERVER` is an `Array` but, the page showing this

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SERVER in B:\xampp\htdocs\creation\myportofolio\v1\source\me-init.php on line 4

please help, i didn't what to do

Comment: Check php.ini/phpinfo for [`variables_order`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)

Comment: I think you should use `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: Please show us _all_ of the relevant code, not just a snippet of it. (The code you've included wouldn't be expected to do anything at all, as nothing calls `init::__construct()`.)

Comment: snippet like what? i write the code just like that and it showing the same error :|

Comment: [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69081), i found a document that said it was a bug, after i restart the apache every are going to normal, i know it's very rare, sorry for not pointing every single lines of my code, but even when i only write a single line of `echo $_SERVER` it showing the same error